# How to align ROI bounding rectangle to main image coordinate

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing, emgucv

I'am decoding a QR code from an image, since the image is large and have other unwanted graphics I'm drawing an roi around the code and decoding it. Everything works, but when i try to draw a bounding box around the QR code, it is drawn somewhere else. How can I align the rectangle in the same area of the main image?

This is what im getting - The red rectangle is the roi, the green one is the bounding box.

[image]

Here is the code :

```
     Image<Gray, byte> Gray_Image = My_Image.Convert<Gray, byte>();
    Gray_Image.ROI = Coderect;
         Gray_Image._Not();

        CvInvoke.cvThreshold(Gray_Image,Gray_Image,50,255.0,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        Gray_Image.Dilate(5);

        

        StructuringElementEx element = new StructuringElementEx(3, 3, 1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_ELEMENT_SHAPE.CV_SHAPE_RECT);
        CvInvoke.cvMorphologyEx(Gray_Image, Gray_Image, IntPtr.Zero, element, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_MORPH_OP.CV_MOP_CLOSE, 18);

        var contour = Gray_Image.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL);
      

        CvInvoke.cvRectangle(My_Image, new Point(contour.BoundingRectangle.X, contour.BoundingRectangle.Y), new Point(contour.BoundingRectangle.X + contour.BoundingRectangle.Width, contour.BoundingRectangle.Y + contour.BoundingRectangle.Height), new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), 4, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED, 0);
    


        pictureBox1.Image = My_Image.Bitmap;
```

Comment: I think some code examples would be useful.

Comment: @JonasH - Have updated the code.

Comment: It seems that you are processing an ROI but draw the rectangle as if you had processed the whole image. By the way, doesn't your decoder return a bonding box ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Im using zxing, it returns a bounding box, but to speed up operation im only processing the code within the roi.

Comment: My question is, how do i overlay or just draw the rectangle in the original image area.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comments.

Comment: FindContours returns **multiple things**, not just a list of contours (I hope). *then*, you call methods/properties on that list of contours that make no sense... granted, I'm unfamiliar with the C# wrappers around OpenCV (familiar with OpenCV), but this looks like it shouldn't even work

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it does work. there are multiple processes going on, I have just posted the part where i stuck. Im using the contour bounding box to draw a rectangle around the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Since I know the (roiX,roiY) of the roi and i also know the (bbX,bbY,bbW,bbH) of the bounding box.
By adding the X of roi and X of bounding box i got the X of the location, similarly for Y.

I simply had to do the following :

```
    cvInvoke.cvRectangle(My_Image, new Point(roiX+bbX, roiY+bbY), new Point((roiX+bbX)+bbW,(roiY+bbY)+bbH), new McvScalar(0,255,0), Line_Type.Eight_Connected,0);
```